# Htaccess rewrite directories to file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
# php_value session.cookie_domain .rhr.fm

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^(data|cache)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Hello once again Stackoverflow!

I would like to redirect URLs for SEO on my website, that

> www.example.com/**about**
>
> www.example.com/?page=**about**

and

> www.example.com/**about/**
>
> www.example.com?page=**about**

But the dirs `data` and `cache` get excluded, so that

> www.example.com/data/js/page.js

does **not** redirect to

> www.example.com/?page=data/js/page.js

I've tried the code above but that didn't work out - `$_GET['page']` allways dumps `index.php`.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^(data|cache)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

2nd rule will skip all files and directories from rewrite due to 2 `RewriteCond` statements.

Comment: @anubhava when I try this in a wordpress environment, the first rule regarding data and cache directories does not take. Any ideas?

Comment: For wordpress you will need to use WP rewrite API instead of these rules.